# Replace particular character but not if it is inside ()

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I'm looking for a one-line command to make a file more readable.  I want to replace all `;` characters with `newline` unless it is inside a set of `()`.  This is on a firewall, so I can only use bash; no perl etc.

Example input:

```
ProductName: Threat Emulation; product_family: Threat; Destination: (countryname: United States; IP: 127.0.0.1; repetitions: 1) ; FileName: (file_name: myfile) ;
```

Expected output:

```
ProductName: Threat Emulation
product_family: Threat
Destination: (countryname: United States; IP: 127.0.0.1; repetitions: 1)
FileName: (file_name: myfile)
```

Comment: you mention sed and tr are available, but not perl. while bash is powerful, it's not the best for text processing. is awk available?

Comment: awk is available.

Comment: No chance of nested or unmatched parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit confusing regex for sed but workable

```
sed '
    :a                                                 #mark return point
    s/\(\(^\|)\)[^(]\+\);\s*\([^)]\+\((\|$\)\)/\1\n\3/ #remove ; between ) and (
    ta                                                 #repeat if substitute success
    s/[[:blank:];]\+$//                                #remove ; with spaces at end
    '
```

Breif regex explanation:

- `^\|)` from the line start or `)`
- `[^(]\+` any symbols but `(`
- `;\s*` semicolon with possible space(s)
- `(\|$` up to the line end or `(`

Comment: That worked like a champ.  Any chance at a brief explanation of that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have awk, you can use the parentheses as field separators:

```
awk -F '[()]' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        if ($i) {
            gsub(/; */,"\n",$i)
            printf "%s", $i
            if ($(i+1)) printf "(%s)", $(i+1)
        }
    }
    print ""
}' <<END
ProductName: Threat Emulation; product_family: Threat; Destination: (countryname: United States; IP: 127.0.0.1; repetitions: 1) ; FileName: (file_name: myfile) ;
END
```

```
ProductName: Threat Emulation
product_family: Threat
Destination: (countryname: United States; IP: 127.0.0.1; repetitions: 1) 
FileName: (file_name: myfile)
```

The trailing semicolon gives you a trailing newline.